# Fill in a range of cells based on a column - VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want a range of cells to fill in with specified information but only if column A is "GFR"
I've been able to accomplish this very simply by recording a macro, searching for GFR in Column A, then pasting in information in Columns C and G

My problem is I can't get my macro to do this for me with new data.  It's go over the old data and copy in the information, but I can't replicate it, obviously.

Example data, with columns C and G already filled in with the correct information:

```
Test Name(O)    Result(R)   Units(R)    Result Interpretation Flag(R)   Reference Low(C)    Reference High(C)   Reference Alpha(C)
GFR     ML/MIN/1.73M2   L           >60
CREATININE                      
POTASSIUM                       
WHITE BLOOD COUNT                       
PLATELET COUNT                      
GLOBULIN                        
GFR     ML/MIN/1.73M2   L           >60
CREATININE                      
POTASSIUM                       
SGOT (AST)
```

I need a hint on how to start this out.
If Column A = GFR, then Column C of the same row = ML/MIN/1.73M2, and column G of the same row = >60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it...

```
Sub FillIn()

   Dim LR As Long

   With ActiveSheet
      LR = Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      For i = LR To 1 Step -1
         If (.Range("A" & i).Value = "GFR") Then
            .Range("C" & i).Value = "ML/MIN/1.73M2"
            .Range("G" & i).Value = ">60"
         End If
      Next i
   End With

End Sub
```